# Change UITableviews height to fit its content in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I need to make `UITaableView` to fit its content.I m loading array data in `UITableView`.But when I fixed some static size ,eventhough the items are less it is showing the extra space.So I need to make  dynamic height to `UITableView` but could not achieve it ..

```
autocompleteTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 140, 200, self.autocompleteTableView.contentSize.height) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        autocompleteTableView.delegate = self;
        autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self;
        autocompleteTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
       [self.view addSubview:autocompleteTableView];
```

When I write this I could not see the TableView itself..How can I get it ?

Comment: you can get a sample example hear : http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/

Comment: I need UITableView's height not UITableViewcells height.How can I do it ?

Comment: UITableview cant set initwithFrame..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **`dynamic tableview height`**. You need to apply dynamic frame.

For ex,

```
myTable.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,w,[row count] * 44);
```

Where 44 is default size of tableview cell

Thus, you need to know each cell height, In order to apply this.

Enjoy Programming

Answer (score 0):

You try the following code

```
CGRect tblFrame = [tableView frame];
[tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(tblFrame.origin.x, 
                                tblFrame.origin.y, 
                                tblFrame.size.width, 
                                tblFrame.size.height + 20)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this method before creating a table view in view did Load. It calculates the Height of the content and and returns total height of table view

```
-(NSInteger)calculateheightOfText{

    for (int i=0; i<[yourarray count]; i++) {
        NSString *cellText =[yourarray objectAtIndex:i];
        UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:17.0];
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        heightOfTableview = heightOfTableview+labelSize.height + 20;
    }
    heightOfTableview = heightOfTableview +([items count]*35);

    return heightOfTableview;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can get your content(text) height and then according to this height you can adjust your tableView frame.

```
CGSize size = [@"Your string" 
               sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT" size:22] 
               constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
```