# How to fix the height of tableviewcell based on webview height? (i am loading webview in each tableviewcell)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

// `I am loading **HTML file** in **UIWebview** which is located on **tableviewcell**.`

I want to fix height for cell based on HTML file height.

**Note:** loading HTML file will be different for every cell.(height is not constant for every HTML file)

Comment: Please try this below link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448426/change-uitableviews-height-to-fit-its-content-in-xcode/13448610#13448610

May it helps you. :)

Comment: For example [Try This Answer][1],
hope it helps


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4890119/1091539

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the height of `UIWebView` object, **first you need to load them**. Then inside the delegate method of `UIWebView` you can get the height as per the html content like given below.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"%f",myWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height);
}
```

you can also get the height of `UIWebView` by JS insertion like this

```
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight;"];
```

In `webViewDidFinishLoad` method you have to **store height based on webview object tag**.

After that load your table and in below method **give height accordingly**.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Any help in swift?And I don't clear that topic "In webViewDidFinishLoad method you have to store height based on webview object tag."

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly..

Here you sets cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode and number of lines, for cell.textLabel. (0 - infinity)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

       cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
       cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
   }

   cell.textLabel.text = [news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   return cell;
```

}

Here you need to count the height of cell.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
    NSString *cellText = [news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20.0f];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(320.0f, MAXFLOAT);

    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont 
                            constrainedToSize:constraintSize 
                                lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return labelSize.height + 20.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement the UITableViewDelegate method    **- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *text = [self getItemForKey:kSummary];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    //You will need to define kDefaultCellFont
    CGSize labelSize = [text sizeWithFont:kDefaultCellFont 
                    constrainedToSize:constraintSize 
                        lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return labelSize.height + ANY_OTHER_HEIGHT;
}
```

If you want more check the [Link](http://sugartin.info/2012/11/19/add-dynamically-height-of-the-uitableview-for-the-comment-section/)